# C switch case default always executes

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement, case, default

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '4') {
    switch (c) {
        case '1':
            printf("You pressed 1");
            break;
        case '2':
            printf("You pressed 2");
            break;
        case '3':
            printf("You pressed 3");
            break;
        case '4':
            break;
        default:
            printf("%c Wrong input, try again\n", c);
            printMenu();
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

ok, so i don't understand why default always executes.  when i press either 1-3 it prints the massage in that case and right after it goes to execute the default case. what's wrong with the code?

Comment: why do you need a break?

Comment: Why the hell are people saying to `break` in the default case? The last case in a `switch` doesn't need a break!

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/201777/break-on-default-case-in-switch

Comment: @GradyPlayer: Stylistically it's not a bad idea, but the folks coming on here and answering "just add a break" are plain wrong...

Comment: @nneonneo: Is a good style put it. A `default` is just like any other label and can appear in anywhere within a switch statement, including before any `case`-label. If the `default` was on top without a `break` it's same as fallthrough.

Answer (score 11):

If you are typing in characters at the console, then you are probably pressing Enter after your entry. This will appear in `getchar` as a `\n` character, which doesn't appear in any of your `switch` cases.

You can simply choose to add `case '\n': break;` to ignore this case.

Answer (score 3):

When you are reading a character using `scanf` - you will input `y` and press the whitespace character. `y` will be assigned to option (i.e. option - `Y`) and the whitespace character will be in buffer. when you call `scanf` next time present in the buffer, the whitespace character will be assigned to option hence goes to the default case. to avoid this leave a space before %c in `scanf`. this does not happen in case of integers or float.

Use the code below to get expected results :

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '4') {
    getchar();
    switch (c) {
        case '1':
            printf("You pressed 1\n");
            break;
        case '2':
            printf("You pressed 2\n");
            break;
        case '3':
            printf("You pressed 3\n");
            break;
        case '4':
            break;
        default:
            printf("%c Wrong input, try again\n", c);
            //printMenu();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

From the manpage:

> ```
>    fgetc(), getc() and getchar() return the character read as an
>    unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on end of file or error.
> ```

I would try to print the character, both as a `char` and as an `int`, to see what's going on.

```
  while ((c = getchar()) != '4') {
+     printf( "c = %c (%d)\n", (char) c, c );
      switch (c) {
```

Generally, that is sufficient to understand and fix the problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that those breaks don't break the while loop, only the switch.  You are probably entering 1 and `enter` and so the newline is read as a second character from getchar.

Answer (score -6):

Add a break to default. Thats where the problem is.